# formatting the way posts show up

Tags: plugins, categories

I recently installed the *plugin List Category Posts* so that my categories show up on the correlating pages.  It worked great, only it modified they header size, font, and added a horizontal scrollbar instead of wrapping the text to the next line.

[Example page](http://www.knocturnalmag.com/music/)

If you click on the header link and go directly to the post, you'll see what it should look like.

I'm new to wordpress and not sure how to change the post formatting back to 'normal'.  Any advice would be a great help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us what support routes you've taken before and maybe link to the results. Nobody wants to do everything from scratch over and over again.

Comment: this is more a css/formatting question. the plugin code is wrapped in two `<pre>` tags: `<pre>
<pre><ul class="lcp_catlist">` - which is causing the scrollbar(s); is that on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the plugin displays posts in a list format, wrapping them in a UL and LI element respectively. You could re-purpose your theme's CSS stylesheet to display lists differently, but this could have unexpected results and effect the way lists are displayed on other parts of your site. I suggest instead of using a plugin, learn more about creating custom page templates and modifying the loop to display posts from only one category.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop